# How to remove background noise in image without damaging text?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I am processing images for tesseract's ocr. I need help to get rid of the background noise without damaging the text.

Example input image

[image: This is an example image]

I have tried median blurring and removing small connected components ([How do I remove the dots / noise without damaging the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681465/how-do-i-remove-the-dots-noise-without-damaging-the-text)). The problem with connected components is that the noise can have larger connections and I cannot get rid of it without also removing the minus sign. Any suggestion how to move forward?

Comment: You can try to apply the open morphological transformation: erosion followed by dilation using a kernel with 1s in the middle rows and zeros at top and bottom (the minus sign will not be removed because the transformation is "applied horizontally"). Read this: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-ops

Comment: Try different kernel sizes. 5x5, 7x7, 9x9 for instance

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I found a way using erosion followed by removal of small connected components

Answer (score 6):

Since your image is only black/white, you can do simple thresholding and [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to filter the image. If your image input was not black and white, you could do blurring techniques such as `cv2.medianBlur()` or `cv2.GaussianBlur()` to smooth the image as a preprocessing step. Then you could perform morphological operations with various kernel sizes or construct custom kernels with `cv2.getStructuringElement()`. Generally, a larger kernel size (`7x7` or `9x9`) will remove more noise but also remove the desired details as opposed to a smaller kernel (`3x3` or `5x5`). There is a trade off depending on how much noise you want to remove while balancing the amount of details to preserve. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696080/how-to-remove-gradient-background-noise/56696296) answer for colored captchas.

---

Threshold

[image]

Morph close

[image]

Invert image for Tesseract

[image]

Result

> -63 164

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

result = 255 - opening
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('result', result)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(result))
cv2.waitKey()
```